npm install for tedious and msnodesqlv8 fails with node-gyp error
I have been trying to install some modules in my project to query a SQL Server database. I have tried this with msnodesqlv8 and tedious but both give me the same error as shown below. I've tried using VS versions 2022 and 2019 but still get the same error. Anyone have anymore suggestions on what I could do? Thanks in advance!
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Bob\automation\node_modules\msnodesqlv8
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! print_variables
npm ERR! "echo" is not recognized as an internal or external command
npm ERR!  operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Sutdio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for '..\blinding.gyp' exited with code 1 . [C:\Users\Bob\automation\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\build\sqlserverv8.vcxproj]
npm ERR! prebuild-install warn install unable to get local issuer certificate
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.4 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.34931.43) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Sutdio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python312\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Bob\\automation\\node_modules\\msnodesqlv8\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.11.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.15.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Bob\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\20.15.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Bob\\automation\\node_modules\\msnodesqlv8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Bob\\automation\\node_modules\\msnodesqlv8\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Sutdio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'build\\binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Sutdio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:209:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519.28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294.12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Bob\automation\node_modules\msnodesqlv8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok


In your VS2019 installer do you have the "Desktop development with C++" workload installed? (It's mentioned as a prerequisite in the node-gyp documentation.)
